# Get model ID in django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have this in my `views.py`:

```
def movies_popular(request):
    popular_movies = Movie.objects.all()
    template = loader.get_template('streaming/movies_popular.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, { 'popular_movies': popular_movies })
    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

And I want to access my `Movie`'s ID from the template, so I do this:

```
    <h2>{{ movie.title }}</h2>
    {% with movie.id|stringformat:"s" as movie_id %}
    {% endwith %}
    <p>Testing ID: "{{ movie_id }}"<p/>
    <p>{{ movie.description }}</p>
```

But `movie_id` is empty.

Answer (score 5):

This line `<p>Testing ID: "{{ movie_id }}"<p/>` should be within the `with` block:

```
<h2>{{ movie.title }}</h2>
{% with movie.id|stringformat:"s" as movie_id %}
<p>Testing ID: "{{ movie_id }}"<p/>
{% endwith %}
<p>{{ movie.description }}</p>
```

The scope of `movie_id` is just within the `with` block.

Comment: It works, but it's completely pointless, as there is no need to explicitly convert to string in a template. `{{ movie.id }}` would work fine.